# Duplicated tablefootnotes with longtabu

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabu

I Have a very wide table that where I want to have footnotes.

I found that one way to make the table fit in my page was to use `tabu` and `longtable`. And the package `tablefootnote` for the in table footnotes.

However now each time I compile, I get duplicated tablefootnotes but not the simple footnotes.

```
\documentclass{arcticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
blablabla\footnote{this is a footnote}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{longtabu}to \textwidth{|X[1]|X[2]|X[3]|}%|l|l|l|
\hline 
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ 
\hline 
c & b & a\tablefootnote{this is a tablefootnote.} \\ 
\hline 
\end{longtabu} 
\caption{Messages description}
\label{tab:messagedesc}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

In this example, I will get one footnote for the simple footnote and 3 for the table footnote.

Comment: you have a longtable/tabu construct which is for multi-page tables but have it inside a table environment so it can not possibly break. If you need it in a float then a normal tabular 9or tabu) mot a long version is what you want. Also avoid using `[h]` which vastly increases the chance of the table going to the end of the document. use `[htp]` to give latex a chance to set it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to have a reference to that table and also display it in my list of tables.

Comment: longtable and table each (separately) allow references and put things in the list of tables. But if you nest one inside the other you remove all longtable features. A table in a box can never break over a page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do I make a label to the longtabu and print it caption? I couldn't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: assuming it is like longtable just use `\\\caption{my caption\label{foo}} \\`  ie the caption is a complete row of the table.

Comment: @MSIS Check `longtable`’s manual page 5 (first paragraph). How to set a caption and reference it is documented there.

Comment: @Sveinung & David Carlisle : Thanks. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle already pointed out, you cannot have page breaks within a floating environment. You can, however, use the usual `longtable` syntax to include the caption in the table's first head. According to the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf), the `\caption` is handled like a `\multicolumn` over the whole table width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
blablabla\footnote{this is a footnote}

\begin{longtabu}to \textwidth{|X[1]|X[2]|X[3]|}%|l|l|l|
\caption{Messages description}\label{tab:messagedesc} \\
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\hline 
\endlastfoot
c & b & a \\
c & b & a\footnote{this is a tablefootnote.} \\ 
\end{longtabu} 

\end{document}
```

This eliminates also the need for the special `\tablefootnote`s within the `longtabu` environment.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but it looks like there's a hiden table which is not referenced. Maybe longtabu gets it's own refence but doesn't print it?

Comment: @MSIS This is a known feature in `longtable` (and `longtabu` use the same code). Use the label command as David Carlisle recommend, or you have to manually reduce the `counter` for tables.

Comment: @hakaze I think your answer will give wrong numbering of the tables.

Comment: @Sveinung: I revised my answer. Now footnotes and the table numbering should work properly.

Comment: @hakaze: What I did is that I removed '\captionof...' and placed '\caption{my caption\label{foo}} \' as david suggested and it works fine! I will post the answer as soon as I'm allowed too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following based on the comments of @DavidCarlisle and the answer of @hakaze

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tabu,longtable} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document} 
blablabla\footnote{this is a footnote} 

\begin{center} 
\begin{longtabu}to \textwidth{|X[1]|X[2]|X[3]|}%|l|l|l|
\caption{my caption\label{foo}} \\
\hline  
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} \\  
\hline  
c & b & a \\ 
c & b & a\footnote{this is a tablefootnote.} \\  
c & b & a \\ 
\hline  
\end{longtabu}  
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Thank you all!